# Strange line showing up in output

Tags: linux, bash

So I have a line in my script which is basically:

```
echo "********************"
echo "AVAILABILITY"
echo "********************"
ssh -p22 -q -o "BatchMode=yes" -o "ConnectTimeout=5" user@ipaddress echo "2>&1" && echo 'Available' || echo 'Not, available'
```

The second half of || outputs fine

ex:

```
********************
AVAILABILITY
********************
Not, available
```

The first half however outputs this annoying blank line:

```
********************
AVAILABILITY
********************

Available
```

I've tried piping the whole line to sed, and tail, and i've tried inserting these right after the first echo and still this weird blank line shows up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command (simplified):

```
ssh user@ipaddress echo "2>&1" && echo 'Available' || echo 'Not, available'
```

The first `echo` is run on the remote machine, and `"2>&1"` redirects the stderr of that echo command to stdout. `echo` with no parameters outputs a newline. This newline is then returned as the stdout of the `ssh` command and appears in your local shell. If the `ssh` command fails (i.e. Not available), then the remote `echo` command never runs, and the newline doesn't appear.

Comment: So giving echo some sort of parameter will automatically negate the new line? Or is there a specific parameter I can give it.

Comment: Or just don't run `echo` on the remote machine.  If you want no output, use `/bin/true` or (if you must!) `cat /dev/null` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress the new line by using echo -n "$(2>&1)"

Thanks to Josh Jolly for helping me understand why the "blank" line was showing up.